# Is there any way to use the video class in my code

Tags: java, arrays

I am unable to use the video class in my program.My code i running fine but according the question i should make use of the video class

But I'am getting the desired output without using it

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
class Video{
     String videoName;
     boolean checkout;
     int rating;
     Video(String name){
         videoName=name;
     }
     String getName(){
         return videoName;
     }
     void doCheckout(){

     }
     void doReturn(){


         }
     void receiveRating(int rating){
         this.rating=rating;
     }
     int getRating(){
         return rating;
     }
     boolean getCheckout(){
         return checkout;
     }
 }
```

videoStore extends the video class but there is no  use with methods of video class the videoStore array values are resetting after every execution i dont know why

```
class VideoStore extends Video{
    String videoStore[]=new String[100];
    int rating[]=new int[100];
    boolean status[]=new boolean[100];
    int i=0,ind=0,len=-1;
    VideoStore(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
    void addVideo(String name){
        videoStore[i]=name;
        status[i]=false;
        i++;
        len++;


    }
    void doCheckout(String name){
        if(len>=0){
        int index=index(name);
        status[index]=true;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Nothig in inventory");
        }

    }
    void doReturn(String name){
        if(len>=0){
        int index=index(name);
        status[index]=false;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Nothing in inventory");
        }

    }
    void receiveRating(String name,int rating){
        if(len>=0){
        int index=index(name);
        this.rating[index]=rating;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Nothing in inventory");
        }
    }
    void listInventory(){
        if(len!=-1){
        for(int p=0;p<=len;p++){
            System.out.println(videoStore[p]+"\t"+status[p]+"\t"+rating[p]);
        }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("nothing in inventory");
        }

    }
    int index(String name){
        for (int i = 0; i < videoStore.length; i++) {
            if(videoStore[i].equals(name)){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

 }
```

**this is the main method**

```
public class VideoLauncher   {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String yn="y";
        int option=0;
        String  videoName="";
        VideoStore vs=new VideoStore(videoName);
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        do{
        System.out.println("1.Add video");
        System.out.println("2.Checkout video");
        System.out.println("3.Return video");
        System.out.println("4.recieve rating");
        System.out.println("5.List inventory");
        System.out.println("6.Exit");
        System.out.println("please enter the option from 1..6");
        option=sc.nextInt();

            switch(option){
            case 1: 
                System.out.println("please enter the video name");
                        videoName=sc.next();
                        Video v=new Video(videoName);
                        vs.addVideo(videoName);
                        System.out.println("video added successfully");
                        System.out.println("do you want to continue(y) else (n)");
                        yn=sc.next();
                        break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("please enter the name of the video to checkout");
                videoName=sc.next();
                vs.doCheckout(videoName);
                System.out.println("Video "+videoName+" checkedout successfully");
                System.out.println("do you want to continue(y) else (n)");
                yn=sc.next();
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("please enter the name of the video to return");
                videoName=sc.next();
                vs.doReturn(videoName);
                System.out.println("Video "+videoName+" returned successfully");
                System.out.println("do you want to continue(y) else (n)");
                yn=sc.next();
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("enter the videoname");
                videoName=sc.next();
                System.out.println("enter the rating");
                int rating=sc.nextInt();
                vs.receiveRating(videoName,rating);
                System.out.println("rating "+rating+" for video"+videoName+" recorded");
                System.out.println("do you want to continue(y) else (n)");
                yn=sc.next();
                break;
            case 5:

                vs.listInventory();
                System.out.println("do you want to continue(y) else (n)");
                yn=sc.next();
                break;
            case 6:
                yn="n";
                System.out.println("exiting");
                break;
            default :
                System.out.println("please enter proper option");

            }

        }while(yn.equals("y"));


    }

}
```

Comment: To use Video Class methods you must use `VideoStore` like `Video vs=new VideoStore(videoName)`
Read more about inheritance and Polymorphic behaviour [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html]

Comment: I didn't find anything wrong in program.It is working fine for me.If you mean by "array values are getting reset after every execution" that after completing program values are lost, then I would like to tell you that java only stores data in memory.For permanent storage you need database.

Comment: the code is working but is there any way that i can make use of the video class in the code @jaspreet

Comment: when `VideoStore` extends `Video` you say, `VideoStore` is a `Video` which is wrong, what you want to say is `VideoStore` has `Video`s. What you need is a list of `Video`s in your `VideoStore`

Comment: Unrelated, but you could simplify your `switch` statement considerably by removing the "y/n" prompt from each case and putting it after the switch.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to give you the whole code but just get you started.

When `VideoStore` extends `Video` you are saying, `VideoStore` **is a** `Video` which is wrong, what you want to say is `VideoStore` **has** `Video`s. What you need is a list of `Video`s in your `VideoStore`

So your `VideoStore` should look something like that:

```
class VideoStore {
    Video[] videos = new Video[100];

    void addVideo(String name) {
        Video v = new Video(name);
        for(int i=0; i<videos.length; i++) {
            if(videos[i] == null) {
                videos[i] = v;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    void doCheckout(String name) {
        int index = index(name);
        videos[index].setCheckout(true);
    }

    void doReturn(String name) {
        // your code
    }

    void receiveRating(String name, int rating) {
        // your code
    }

    void listInventory() {
       // your code
    }

    int index(String name) {
        // your code
    }

}
```

And to your interrogation:

> the videoStore array values are resetting after every execution i dont know why

this is normal, they are only in memory and will be wiped out once the program terminates.